# how to set putty logfile using putty command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, putty

I'am using putty 0.63 as CLI in windows batch script, i need to print all the output in the putty console to a log file,

I'am using the following command in my script:( putty.exe -x -t -ssh -2 -l %USERNAME% %IP_ADDRESS% -m commands.txt)

I tried the session configuration and use the (-load ) param,but it didn't help me since it is required a manual GUI configuration, and i need an automated way.

What should I do to print the output to a log file?

Please Advise

Comment: -load loads the session configuration from registry. You can automate the setting up reg putty session using reg import.

Comment: @foxidrive adding >file.log is not helping the putty console printing nothing

Comment: @mihai_mandis do you have example about automating the putty registry setup

Comment: I see now that putty is an interactive telnet client, not a command line tool.  I don't think you can log the output with redirection or piping.

Comment: there's plink.exe tool in putty package. It is a command line tool. So passing command as parameters and redirections are used with plink.exe. About the connections configuration path for putty and putty tool - it is provided in the response below. Under S...\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\ you can find all sessions saved in putty.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by windows reg update
the putty store the configuration in the registry:
The path to the key is:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER
    \Software
        \SimonTatham
            \PuTTY
                \Sessions
                    \Default%20Settings

1- create a reg file for example "settings.reg"
 content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\Default%20Settings]
"LogFileName"="C:\\..path..\\mylogfile.log"
"LogType"=dword:00000002
```

in my batch file, i added this line before executing putty.exe

```
 `reg import settings.reg`
 `putty -x -t -ssh -2 -l root 10.56.56.35 -m commands.txt`
```